# Error: incompatible types when initializing type 'int' using type ' '

Tags: c, incompatibility

I am creating a program, which involves data from file. 
In one of the functions i get the error incompatible types when initializing type 'int' using type 'datte' when i try to compile it

datte, clocck and games are structs.

```
games create_match(int round, int goals_home_team, int goals_visiting_team, int spectators, char home_team[MAX_TEAM_NAME], char visiting_team[MAX_TEAM_NAME],
                   datte day,
                   clocck otim)
{
  games result = { round, day, otim, "", "", goals_home_team, goals_visiting_team, spectators };

  strcpy(result.home_team, home_team);
  strcpy(result.visiting_team, visiting_team);

  return result;
}
```

My compiler says that the error is at the line "games result =re...".

I have another function from another program, which is identical, but that one has no problem compiling

kamp, dato and klokke are structs

```
kamp lav_kamp(int runde, dato dato, klokke klokke,
              char hjemmehold[MAX_HOLD_NAVN], char udehold[MAX_HOLD_NAVN],
              int hjemmemaal, int udemaal, int tilskuere)
{
    kamp res =
        { runde, dato, klokke, "", "", hjemmemaal, udemaal, tilskuere };
    strcpy(res.hjemmehold, hjemmehold);
    strcpy(res.udehold, udehold);
    return res;
}
```

So what i don't understand is why the first function can't compile, but the second one can.

EDIT:

The 3 structs

```
typedef struct games
{
  int round_of_games,

      spectators,

      goals_home_team,

      goals_visiting_team;

  char home_team[MAX_TEAM_NAME],

       visiting_team[MAX_TEAM_NAME];

  clocck otim;

  datte datte;

} games;


typedef struct clocck
{
  int tim_hour,

      tim_min;

} clocck;


typedef struct datte

{

  int odate_day,

      odate_year;

  enum odate_month 

  {

    January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, Septemper, October, November, December

  } odate_month;

} datte;
```

Comment: The definition of `games` would be helpful.

Comment: All those custom types, how are they defined? Not only `games`, but `datte` and `clocck` etc.

Comment: The 3 structs have been added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you can't just initialize a structure in any order, you must initialize it in the exact order the member fields was declared in the structure.

For example, in your `games` structure you declared the `datte` member last, as the eight member. That means that the `day` variable in your `create_match` function must be the last in the initialization.

So instead of e.g.

```
games result = { round, day, ... };
```

You must write

```
games result = { round, ..., day };
```

You must also make sure the other values in the initialization of `result` is in the correct order in the structure.

Comment: In C99 you can use designated initializers to initialize the members of the structure in any order you like, e.g.: `games result = { .round_of_games = round, .datte = day, .otim = otim, .goals_home_team = goals_home_team, .goals_visiting_team = goals_visiting_team, .spectators = spectators };`.

Answer (score 0):

As the compiler warns, you are trying to initialise the `int` field

```
result.spectators
```

with `day` which is type `datte` in your code:

```
games result = { round, day, otim, "", "", goals_home_team, goals_visiting_team, spectators };
```

In addition, (at least in MSVC compiler) the fields in a nested `struct` need to be itemised. That would give the initialisation as:

```
games result = { round, spectators, goals_home_team, goals_visiting_team, "", "", 
        otim.tim_hour, otim.tim_min, day.odate_day, day.odate_year, day.odate_month };
```